# iPhone OS 2.2.1 Back up

Tags: iphone

I know by this time that there is no way to down grade from 3.0 to 2.2.1.
So, can any one tell me how to take the back up of the iPhone device with 2.2.1.

Thank you All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will not be able to restore from that backup to get 2.2.1** after you have upgraded to 3.0.

However, if you want to make a backup, simply connect your phone to your PC or Mac and itunes should back it up automatically.

If it doesn't, right click on the iPhone icon in the left panel of iTunes and select "Backup".

The backup will back up your settings and documents, and you might be able to restore those using that backup.

To restore, connect your iphone and hit the "Restore" button in the iTunes page for your phone.

Comment: thanks Alex,
can u please clarify a bit on this? Like how to back up it and how to restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can downgrade your Firmware:
http://www.blogsdna.com/2733/how-to-downgrade-iphone-firmware-30-to-221.htm

Backup: If you've a jailbroken device, you could use SSH to access your needed files.. I don't think that there is an "easy" way to load a 3.0 Backup to a 2.2.1 phone (if I've understood your question correctly).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned more about the data rather than its formatting, then I suggest you to go with tweaking [the SQL source](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), its fully C based. Its really a painful process. As Afit said you will endup junks in between the valid chars.